# Extracting text and number from multiple files in linux

Tags: linux, sed

What would be the best command to extract the bold texts and numbers from the lines below?

2015-04-21 17:53:00Z,**Mike**,**47176121**,16,,0.0

2015-04-21 17:53:00Z,**Rob**,**45423252**,16,,0.0

I have tired `sed 's/.*[\(.*\).\([0-9]*\).*/\1 \2/'`

The output I require is:

Mike 47176121

Rob 45423252

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about `cut -f 2,3 -d,` instead of trying do sed

Comment: `cut -f 2,3 -d, --output-delimiter=' '`, but yeah, `cut` seems like a good fit. If GNU cut (I believe `--output-delimiter` is GNU-specific) is not available, `awk -F, '{ print $2, $3 }'` is a sane replacement.